# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError - solved for Angular v4

Tags: angular, observable

The question here is:  Is there a better architecture for my app so I can avoid the solution that is in the Angular Docs, which seems like a hack.  (Sorry Angular Team, love you!)

This error has been driving coders crazy and as a newbie to coding I was very lost for much of a day.  Lots of advice out there and really strange hacks to make it go away, at least strange for noobs.  So I'm going to post my solution at the request of a guy who knows vastly more than me.

The best explanation of this error that I found is this by Maxim Koretskyi:
https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

However, I was thrown off track and lost more hours.  If you scroll down to "Possible fixes" it seems that he recommends against the two solutions and that we should re-architect our apps.  While I agree with him I couldn't figure out what to do, and since I couldn't find specific re-architecting solutions, I eventually went with the "Asynchronous update" of the two "Possible fixes" he mentions.

That works but sure feels like a hack.  It is in the Angular Docs as the solution, although it was difficult for me to figure out how that example applied to my app.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview

Re-architecting seems more professional but there aren't useful examples online that I could find.  Lots of the Stack Overflow posts don't include whole components, only cryptic parts which are hard for a noob to learn from.  Often I had to guess what the components were.  Confusing.

So here is the relevant sections of my app components and my solution.  I hope it saves a lot of hours for other newbie coders!

**all-projects.component.html** In the html there is a click event when the user wants to edit a project.

```
<md-list-item class="items" *ngFor="let project of projects">
    <li fxFlex="30" class="badge" (click)="goToDetailPage(project)">
         <span> {{ project.projectName }} </span>
    </li>
    <li fxFlex="20" class="item"> {{ project.projectOwner }} </li>
...
```

**all-projects.component.ts**  That click event calls goToDetailPage(project) that includes the project database key, in this case Firebase, and triggers the navigation to the edit component (below) and filling in the selected project detail from the database.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ProjectsAdminService } from './project-admin.service';
import { ConfirmService } from '../../../shared/confirm.service';
import { Project } from './project-admin.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-projects',
  templateUrl: './all-projects.component.html'
})

export class AllProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  projects: Project[];
  private selectedId: number;
  private result: boolean;
  allProjects: Project[];


  constructor(
      private projectsAdminService: ProjectsAdminService,
      private router: Router,
      private confirmService: ConfirmService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectsAdminService.getProjects()
        .subscribe(
            projects => this.allProjects = this.projects = projects
        );
  }


  // Create the URL param key to be parsed in the edit-project     component.

  goToDetailPage(selectedProject) {
    this.router.navigate(['/loggedin/admin/projectsAdmin/editProject',        selectedProject.$key]);
  };


  deleteProject(selectedProject) {
    // Call the confirm dialog component
    this.confirmService
        .confirm('Confirm Delete', 'This action is final. Gone forever!')
        .do(res => {if (res === true)   {this.projectsAdminService.deleteProject(selectedProject.$key);
        }})
        .subscribe(res => this.result = res, err => err);
  }

}
```

**edit-project.component.ts**  This is where the problem was, in ngOnInit.  I tried ngAfterViewInit but it didn't help. Maxim explains how this problem arises in Angular's Lifecyle Hooks.  Wrapping the function call in setTimeout gave the computer a bit more time to deal with the changes and fixed the problem.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ProjectsAdminService } from './project-admin.service';
import { Project } from './project-admin.model';
import { AddEditFormComponent } from './add-edit-form.component';

import { SuccessService } from '../../../shared/success.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-project',
  templateUrl: './edit-project.component.html'
})

export class EditProjectComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  project: Project;

  @ViewChild(AddEditFormComponent)
  private addEditForm: AddEditFormComponent;

  private projectId: string;
  private projectData;

  private success() {
    this.successService
        .openDialog('Database updated as you wished!');
  }


  constructor(
      private projectsAdminService: ProjectsAdminService,
      private successService: SuccessService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router
  ) {}

// Need to load the data after the form is rendered so ngOnInit didn't work.

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.fetchProject();
    });
  }


  // Parse the URL for the project id number or $key.

  fetchProject() {
    this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
      this.projectId = urlParameters['id'];
    });

    // Display the data retrieved from the data model to the form model.

    this.projectsAdminService.getProjectById(this.projectId)

        .subscribe(dataLastEmittedFromObserver => {
          this.projectData = dataLastEmittedFromObserver;

          this.addEditForm.addEditProjectForm.setValue({
            projectOwner: this.projectData.projectOwner,
            projectOwnerKey: this.projectData.projectOwnerKey,
            setupDate: this.projectData.setupDate,
           ...
          });
        });
  }


// Add error handling and success message linked to Firebase results.

  update() {
    this.project = this.prepareSaveProject();
    this.projectsAdminService.updateProject(this.projectId, this.project);
    this.reset();
    this.success();
    this.router.navigate(['/loggedin/admin/projectsAdmin/searchProjects']);
  }

  prepareSaveProject(): Project {
    const formModel = this.addEditForm.addEditProjectForm.value;

    // return updated `Project` object

    const updatedProject: Project = {
      projectOwner: formModel.projectOwner as string,
      projectOwnerKey: formModel.projectOwnerKey as string,
      setupDate: formModel.setupDate as string,
      ...
    };
    return updatedProject;
  }

  reset() {
    this.addEditForm.addEditProjectForm.reset();
  }

  cancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['/loggedin/admin/projectsAdmin/searchProjects']);
  }

}
```

**edit.project.component.html**  Per request, added on 7/24/2017:

```
<md-card class="form-card">
        <h2 fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">Edit Project Form</h2><br>
        <app-add-edit-form></app-add-edit-form>

        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
            <button [disabled]="!addEditForm.addEditProjectForm.valid" md-raised-button (click)="update(addEditForm.addEditProjectForm.value)">Save Edits</button>
            <button md-raised-button (click)="cancel()">Cancel Edit</button>
        </div>
</md-card>
```

**add-edit-form.component.html**    Per request, added on 7/24/2017:

```
 <section>
    <H4>Search members to add owners</H4>
    <app-add-owner
            (onSelected)="onSelected($event)">
    </app-add-owner>
  </section>


  <form [formGroup]="addEditProjectForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addEditProjectForm.value)"
        [class.error]="!addEditProjectForm.valid && addEditProjectForm.touched">

    <ul class="items">

      <li>
        <label>Project owner: </label><br><br>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" id="projectOwner" formControlName="projectOwner"  required>
      </li>

      <li class="hiddenField">
        <label>Project owner key: </label><br><br>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" id="projectOwnerKey" formControlName="projectOwnerKey"  required>
      </li>

      <li>
        <label>Setup Date (Year/Month/Day):</label><br><br>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" id="setupDate" formControlName="setupDate"  required>
      </li>

      <div>
      <li>
        <label>Check if new project - 95% equity available: </label><br><br>
        <input #newProject type="checkbox" id="newProject" formControlName="newProject">
      </li>

      <li *ngIf="newProject.checked == false">
        <label>If partially complete project, percent of project equity available: </label><br><br>
        <input class="percentField" type="text" id="percentAvailable" formControlName="percentAvailable"> %
      </li>
      </div>

      <li>
        <label>Project name: </label><br><br>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" id="projectName" formControlName="projectName" required>
      </li>

      <li><label>Put project in stealth mode?</label><br><br>
        <label><input type="radio" formControlName="stealthMode" [value]="true"/>  Yes</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" formControlName="stealthMode" [value]="false"/>  No</label>
      </li>
(...)
```

**project-admin.service.ts**  So I don't leave anyone guessing about the other part of this issue I'm including my related service for CRUDing my database.

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';

import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Project } from './project-admin.model';
import { SuccessService } from '../../../shared/success.service';


@Injectable()
export class ProjectsAdminService {

  private projects$: FirebaseListObservable<Project[]>;

  constructor(
      private af: AngularFireDatabase,
      private successService: SuccessService,
      @Inject(FirebaseApp) fb) {
        this.projects$ = af.list('Projects');
  }


  // Get all projects.

  public getProjects(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
    return this.af.list('Projects', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'projectName'
      }
    });
  }


  // Fetch project detail for project list from click event.

  public getProjectById(projectId: string) {
    return this.af.object('Projects/' + projectId);
  }

  // Create new project

  public addProject(newProject: Project): void {
    this.projects$.push(newProject)
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
  }

  // Update an existing project

  public updateProject(key: string, value: any): void {
    this.projects$.update(key, value)
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
  }

  // Deletes a single project and calls for success modal window.

  public deleteProject(key: string): void {
    this.af.object('/Projects/' + key).remove()
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
        .then(_ => this.success());
  }

  private success() {
    this.successService
        .openDialog('Database updated as you wished!');
  }

  // Default error handling for all actions

  private handleError(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

}
```

That's it.  Maybe there is a way of re-architecting this setup but I don't see it.  Any discussion and better solutions are appreciated!

Comment: hey, can you post the template for `project-edit-component.ts` and `AddEditFormComponent` code and template and the precise error description? `all-projects.component` seems to be irrelavant here as I understand you're navigating away from it and it's destroyed

Comment: I added the html components Maximus. :-)

Comment: great, but we also need `AddEditFormComponent` code and the precise error description :)